# Query on database to select id and password not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here it is my query to find username and password stored in mysql db made using codeigniter php framework.

```
 public function find_user($username,$password)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM users_login
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($username,md5($password)));

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

where the db is made: `id,username,password`. there is some mistake because it doesn't work as should be?

Here it is my controller. Maybe the error it is here:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database(); /* This function it's used to connect to database */
        $this->load->model('User','user'); /* This call the model to retrieve data from db */
    }


    public function index()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/login.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_pass');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['title'] = "User Access";
            $this->load->view('login', $data);
        }
        else 
        {   
            $data['title'] = " ";
            $this->load->view('/templates/index',$data);            
        }
    }

    public function pass_check($pass)
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        $result = $this->user->find_user($username,$pass);

        if($result)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('pass_check','Invalid username or password! Try Again, please!');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: **(1)** What's the question? **(2)** Are you sure you want to use `md5` (which has been broken)? [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) is a better option for password storage.

Comment: I edited the post. I would know if there is some mistake

Comment: Did you try to execute the query locally with two parameters?
Do you get something returned, or nothing?
How is your password stored in the db?

Comment: Do you get errors ? or you get false as return for this function? what is your question?

Comment: Locally the query works well. I didn't receive any error. When I enter data in the login form I enter even if username and password are wrong

Comment: @rdlowrey isn't `sha1` also broken?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, it is. From what I've read, it requires 2**69 operations to get a collision. **Disclaimer** though I'm not a crypto expert by any means, from different readings I've gathered that this is probably still sufficient for run of the mill web application password storage.  Hopefully if you're storing highly sensitive data you aren't browsing this thread as a how-to! Also, **AFAIK** the sha256-384-512 series is essentially of the same style, so upgrading to those would really only mean a stronger brute force. For now, I'm okay storing passwords for a dog-grooming salon site with `sha1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mazzy, first of all, remember this:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Can be written as:

```
return $query->num_rows() == 1;
```

I don't know much about PHP / CodeIgniter preferred syntax, but it is much more compact (and comfortable, for me).

Now, trying to dig on your issue. What does `$query->num_rows()` return for a particular user/password combination that is not present in the DB?

If it is matching something (greater than 0) then you should check the data manually and see if there is a record in the DB matching that user/password combination.